# how to make hyperlink to launch mail on QTextEdit in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I want a hyperlink to launch a mail client in a QTextEdit. I tried this but nothing happens when clicking the link:

```
self.text_area = QTextEdit()
self.text_area.setReadOnly(True)
self.text_area.setText(u'<p> Jhon Doe <a href='"'mailto:jhon@compay.com'"'>jhon@compay.com</a>  </p>')
self.text_area.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse)
```

Comment: any reason why youre using a `QTextEdit` instead of a `QLabel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QTextBrowser`, which is a specialized class that provides a rich text browser with hypertext navigation that inherits from `QTextEdit`, so it has at least the same `QTextEdit` capabilities.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextBrowser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    text_area = QTextBrowser()
    text_area.setText(u'<p> Jhon Doe <a href='"'mailto:jhon@compay.com'"'>jhon@compay.com</a>  </p>')
    text_area.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    text_area.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```